# Monitoring a remote SFTP server for new files with JSCH and WatchService

Tags: java, jsch, watchservice

I am currently using JSCH to implement an SFTP client. This works well for my purposes right now, but in researching `WatchService` for another project it got me wondering if I could implement it with JSCH to monitor the SFTP server for new files.

I am suspecting that it isn't possible right now as WatchService requires a Watchable object to operate off of and as far as I can tell JSCH does not implement Watchable in any way.

Does anyone have any experience with this or ideas on how it could be accomplished given the limitation above?